# How to confirm email address using express/node?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build verification of email address for users, to verify their email is real. What package should I use to confirm the email address of the user? So far Im using mongoose and express

Code Example

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true }
    password: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
   // Create a new User
   var user = new User();
   user.email = req.body.email;
   user.password = req.body.password;
   user.save();
});
```

In the app.post codes, how do i confirm the email address of the user?

Comment: First off, validate the input email is a valid email string.

Comment: Then, have a property called "emailValidated" in the User model. Send an email to the submitted email with a unique link attached to the email. If that link is accessed, set "emailValidated" to true. The link can be accessed only if the user could acess the provided email, thus confirming the user's email.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "account verification" or "email verification". There are plenty of Node modules that can perform this, but the principle goes like this:

- Your User model should have an `active` attribute that is `false` by default
- When the user submits a valid signup form, create a new User (who's `active` will be `false` initially)
- Create a long random string (128 characters is usually good) with a crypto library and store it in your database with a reference to the User ID
- Send an email to the supplied email address with the randomly generated string as part of a link pointing back to a route on your server
- When a user clicks the link and hits your route, check for the string passed in the URL
- If the string exists in the database, get the related user and set their `active` property to `true`
- Delete the string from the database, it is no longer needed

Your user is now verified.

Comment: thanks for this. One question though, how do we ensure the public url endpoint for confirming email doesn't get spammed? (and therefore cause DB performance issues). I guess we should implement authentication? How would this work?

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation, @Soviut... Do you think social signup requires an email validation, or it is not necessary? (and sorry for this very late comment... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS Nope. The whole point of social logins is the user is already assumed to have been verified by the auth provider.

Comment: @Soviut: perfect, thanks again... I just needed a confirmation, I'm quite new on client development...

Comment: Is it important to hash the ID on step 3? Would it be much different from sending the (non hashed) ID and using it in the URL?

Comment: @AlejandroCamus Definitely do NOT send the raw ID! A raw ID would allow bad actors to simply increment the number in the activation URL. Also, I did not say to hash the ID, I said to create a random hash (I've since adjusted this to say random string). Each attempt gets its own new random string associated with it.

Comment: You missed a step, except OP does not care about token expiration but if security is important (which should be) then token should be set to expire after a given period (perhaps 6 hours)

Comment: @Fortune how would you implement token expiration?  like the token will be stored in db along with the the time it will be created, and then we will calculate the time difference form the "created time" and the time of the received query?

Comment: @Fortune yes. You'd store the created date then compare it when a token is checked. If it's past the created date + expiry period, delete it.

Comment: @Soviut I'm implementing my email confirmation with the hash. But I'm a little confused- Why would a bad actor want to verify someone's email? Is it just to be extra safe that a curious person doesn't cause annoyances by verifying peoples emails? What is the motivation for someone to do that?

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss It would allow a bad actor to impersonate someone by signing up with the victim's email address and then verifying it without needing access to the victim's email account making the entire process of email verification ineffective.

Answer (score 39):

```
var express=require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var app=express();
/*
    Here we are configuring our SMTP Server details.
    STMP is mail server which is responsible for sending and recieving email.
*/
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "Your Gmail ID",
        pass: "Gmail Password"
    }
});
var rand,mailOptions,host,link;
/*------------------SMTP Over-----------------------------*/

/*------------------Routing Started ------------------------*/

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
app.get('/send',function(req,res){
        rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 54);
    host=req.get('host');
    link="http://"+req.get('host')+"/verify?id="+rand;
    mailOptions={
        to : req.query.to,
        subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
        html : "Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href="+link+">Click here to verify</a>" 
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
     if(error){
            console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
     }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        res.end("sent");
         }
});
});

app.get('/verify',function(req,res){
console.log(req.protocol+":/"+req.get('host'));
if((req.protocol+"://"+req.get('host'))==("http://"+host))
{
    console.log("Domain is matched. Information is from Authentic email");
    if(req.query.id==rand)
    {
        console.log("email is verified");
        res.end("<h1>Email "+mailOptions.to+" is been Successfully verified");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("email is not verified");
        res.end("<h1>Bad Request</h1>");
    }
}
else
{
    res.end("<h1>Request is from unknown source");
}
});

/*--------------------Routing Over----------------------------*/

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});
```

Follow the code example, you can use `nodemailer` to send the link, and then verify it.
Here is a link: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/node-email-verification-script/

Comment: I could not get why are you checking if the host and protocol are the same. Isn't if they are not the same the request would not even reach our server?

Comment: This email verification code must be in main `app.js` or `index.router.js` ?

Comment: I guess this will work as long as the /send and /verify routes hit to the same server program. I mean if /send request was sent to a server program and for some reason server crashed and restarted, the variable rand will no longer be available to verify the user using /verify route. The variable rand should be stored in the database instead.

Comment: rand should be created using cryptographic lib :(

Comment: @Souban it's in true, you need to save the random file in a DataBase.

Comment: Why does this answer have so many upvotes? `rand` will keep changing with each request to the `/send`, so this won't work unless you only have one user verifying their email at a time.

Answer (score 34):

**Step 1:**

**User Model**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    password: String,
  });
```

**Token Model**

```
const tokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    expireAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, index: { expires: 86400000 } }
});
```

**Step 2: Login**

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        // error occur
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send({msg: err.message});
        }
        // user is not found in database i.e. user is not registered yet.
        else if (!user){
            return res.status(401).send({ msg:'The email address ' + req.body.email + ' is not associated with any account. please check and try again!'});
        }
        // comapre user's password if user is find in above step
        else if(!Bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
            return res.status(401).send({msg:'Wrong Password!'});
        }
        // check user is verified or not
        else if (!user.isVerified){
            return res.status(401).send({msg:'Your Email has not been verified. Please click on resend'});
        } 
        // user successfully logged in
        else{
            return res.status(200).send('User successfully logged in.');
        }
    });

});
```

**Step 3: Sign Up**

```
exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, user) {
    // error occur
    if(err){
        return res.status(500).send({msg: err.message});
    }
    // if email is exist into database i.e. email is associated with another user.
    else if (user) {
        return res.status(400).send({msg:'This email address is already associated with another account.'});
    }
    // if user is not exist into database then save the user into database for register account
    else{
        // password hashing for save into databse
        req.body.password = Bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
        // create and save user
        user = new User({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password });
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { 
              return res.status(500).send({msg:err.message});
            }
            
            // generate token and save
            var token = new Token({ _userId: user._id, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
            token.save(function (err) {
              if(err){
                return res.status(500).send({msg:err.message});
              }

                // Send email (use credintials of SendGrid)
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ service: 'Sendgrid', auth: { user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME, pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD } });
                var mailOptions = { from: 'no-reply@example.com', to: user.email, subject: 'Account Verification Link', text: 'Hello '+ req.body.name +',\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/confirmation\/' + user.email + '\/' + token.token + '\n\nThank You!\n' };
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                    if (err) { 
                        return res.status(500).send({msg:'Technical Issue!, Please click on resend for verify your Email.'});
                     }
                    return res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '. It will be expire after one day. If you not get verification Email click on resend token.');
                });
            });
        });
    }
    
  });

});
```

**Step 4: Verify Account**

```
// It is GET method, you have to write like that
//    app.get('/confirmation/:email/:token',confirmEmail)

exports.confirmEmail = function (req, res, next) {
    Token.findOne({ token: req.params.token }, function (err, token) {
        // token is not found into database i.e. token may have expired 
        if (!token){
            return res.status(400).send({msg:'Your verification link may have expired. Please click on resend for verify your Email.'});
        }
        // if token is found then check valid user 
        else{
            User.findOne({ _id: token._userId, email: req.params.email }, function (err, user) {
                // not valid user
                if (!user){
                    return res.status(401).send({msg:'We were unable to find a user for this verification. Please SignUp!'});
                } 
                // user is already verified
                else if (user.isVerified){
                    return res.status(200).send('User has been already verified. Please Login');
                }
                // verify user
                else{
                    // change isVerified to true
                    user.isVerified = true;
                    user.save(function (err) {
                        // error occur
                        if(err){
                            return res.status(500).send({msg: err.message});
                        }
                        // account successfully verified
                        else{
                          return res.status(200).send('Your account has been successfully verified');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        
    });
});
```

**Step 5: Resend Link**

```
exports.resendLink = function (req, res, next) {

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, user) {
        // user is not found into database
        if (!user){
            return res.status(400).send({msg:'We were unable to find a user with that email. Make sure your Email is correct!'});
        }
        // user has been already verified
        else if (user.isVerified){
            return res.status(200).send('This account has been already verified. Please log in.');
    
        } 
        // send verification link
        else{
            // generate token and save
            var token = new Token({ _userId: user._id, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
            token.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return res.status(500).send({msg:err.message});
                }
    
                // Send email (use credintials of SendGrid)
                    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ service: 'Sendgrid', auth: { user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME, pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD } });
                    var mailOptions = { from: 'no-reply@example.com', to: user.email, subject: 'Account Verification Link', text: 'Hello '+ user.name +',\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/confirmation\/' + user.email + '\/' + token.token + '\n\nThank You!\n' };
                    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                       if (err) { 
                        return res.status(500).send({msg:'Technical Issue!, Please click on resend for verify your Email.'});
                     }
                    return res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '. It will be expire after one day. If you not get verification Email click on resend token.');
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You can take help from this link:https://medium.com/@slgupta022/email-verification-using-sendgrid-in-node-js-express-js-mongodb-c5803f643e09

Comment: While this might answer the question, if you link to your own website or service in your answer, [you *must* disclose your affiliation in the answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Without this disclosure, this could be considered spam, and can result in the link being removed or your post being flagged as such.

Comment: **npm install bcryptjs --save**

Comment: **npm install crypto --save**

Comment: **npm install nodemailer --save**

Comment: When resending the link, shouldn't you check if a token still exists and delete that one first before generating a new one?

Comment: Yeah, you should delete the token if exist.

Comment: Shouldn't you also store the email address in the token object, and then check that the email address hasn't changed meanwhile? Otherwise, I could request a token to my old email address, change my email address in my account, and then verify that new address through the link that was sent to the old address.

Comment: thanks for the detailed solution. however, it seems overly complicated. there is a much simpler way to do this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/email-verification/

Answer (score 25):

I would like to present a slightly different approach from the ones proposed.

**This method does not put the hash into the database (therefore less interaction with it)**

You don't need to register the hash in the database. Here's an overview after receiving a registration request:

1. You encode the user id + registration time
2. You send the token to the user
3. When the user triggers his registration request, you decode the token.
4. Because The decoded token contains the user id + the time, you can
   mark the user as registered by increasing their role
   (registered, subscriber, admin, etc.) for instance

Translated into code, you would have something like this:

**1- Encode the token**

```
function encodeRegistrationToken()
{
    // jsonweb automatically adds a key that determines the time, but you can use any module
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    // The information we need to find our user in the database (not sensible info)
    let info = {id: yourUserId};

    // The hash we will be sending to the user
    const token = jwt.sign(info, "yoursecretkey");

    return token;
}

// ... 
let token = encodeRegistrationToken();
```

**2- Send token to the user via any appropriate way**

```
// Your implementation of sending the token
sendTokenToUser(token);
```

**3- Decode the token**

```
function decodeRegistrationToken(token)
{   
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    let decoded = jwt.verify(token, "yoursecretkey");

    let userId = decoded.id;

    // Check that the user didn't take too long
    let dateNow = new Date();
    let tokenTime = decoded.iat * 1000;

    // Two hours
    let hours = 2;
    let tokenLife = hours * 60 * 1000;

    // User took too long to enter the code
    if (tokenTime + tokenLife < dateNow.getTime())
    {
        return {            
            expired: true
        };
    }

    // User registered in time
    return {
        userID
    };

}
```

**4 - Update your database**

- Upgrade the user role to subscriber

**or**

- Set their "register" key to true

Quick note: You can further encode the user id when encoding your token if you want (it's easily accessible).

Comment: Good Solution !

Comment: How do you invalidate the token after the user confirmed the account?

Comment: You update the user new registration time and compare it with the token creation time. This will invalidate all outdated tokens.

Answer (score 15):

I spent a lot of time figuring out the perfect way to send confirmation mail. Here is the method I used.

**Libraries**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
```

**Step 1**
Encode the user id in a jwt token with an expiration date

```
var date = new Date();
var mail = {
            "id": user.id,
            "created": date.toString()
            }

const token_mail_verification = jwt.sign(mail, config.jwt_secret_mail, { expiresIn: '1d' });

var url = config.baseUrl + "verify?id=" + token_mail_verification;
```

**Step 2**
Send the token to the user email address using nodemailer library

```
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        name: "www.domain.com",
        host: "smtp.domain.com",
        port: 323,
        secure: false, // use SSL
        auth: {
            user: "user@domain.com", // username for your mail server
            pass: "Password", // password
        },

    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"NAME" <user@domain.com>', // sender address
        to: user.email, // list of receivers seperated by comma
        subject: "Account Verification", // Subject line
        text: "Click on the link below to veriy your account " + url, // plain text body
    }, (error, info) => {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return;
        }
        console.log('Message sent successfully!');
        console.log(info);
        transporter.close();
    });
```

**Step 3**
Accept the verification link

```
app.get('/verify', function(req, res) {
    token = req.query.id;
    if (token) {
        try {
            jwt.verify(token, config.jwt_secret_mail, (e, decoded) => {
                if (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    return res.sendStatus(403)
                } else {
                    id = decoded.id;

                
//Update your database here with whatever the verification flag you are using 



                }

            });
        } catch (err) {

            console.log(err)
            return res.sendStatus(403)
        }
    } else {
        return res.sendStatus(403)

    }

})
```

**Step 4**
Have a coffee and **THANK ME** for saving your so much time

PS: This nodemailer SMTP method will even work with your hosting. So no need to go for third party. You can also find ways to use gmail with nodemailer.

Comment: Please mind the security lack on this!
Without invalidating JWT token after the first verification, during the 1day left that endpoint is still opened to directly edit the user stored information. To avoid this is usefull to store the jwt in the database, then check if match on first verification, then destroy it from database, to avoid multiple future verification requests.

Comment: @Nicolò Why would multiple verification requests be a security lack?

Comment: I'd prefer to not keep private information in a jwt as soon as they're no longer required. Not a big danger, but good to keep in mind since the server in "/verify" request has to trust only on that, no session, no auth, no layers.

Comment: After verifying the user it would be convenient to add the token to a blacklist. Invalidate it.

Answer (score 8):

if you are just testing on your local machine, one simple way of understanding how to do it can be :

Assuming you already know sending mails through nodemailer..

Once user signs up, after storing sign-up data in your database, on your server side take user email from sign-up data received and a random generated number and build a custom url with the address of page where user will be directed after he/she clicks on the link given in mail.

```
var customUrl = "http://"+ your host + "/" + your verification web-page + "?email=" + userEmail + "&id=" + randomNumber;
```

An example can be:

```
var userEmail = someone@example.com
var host = localhost:8080
var directWebPage = verifyUserEmail.html
var randomNumber = // generate with math.random() // lets say 111
```

Putting in above format of customUrl it looks something like this

```
customUrl:http://localhost:8080/verifyUserEmail.htmlemail=someone@example.com&id=111
```

Save this customUrl somewhere (probably in your database)
Now, send an email to user with email body containing this cutomUrl link.

```
<a href="customUrl">Click to verify your email</a>
```

When user clicks on the link he/she will be directed to ***verifyUserEmail.html*** page and when that happens you can extract the page ***url*** containing ***email*** and ***id*** information

For example in angular I go like this-

```
var urlVerifyData = $location.url(); or $location.absUrl();
```

Now extract ***email*** form ***urlVerifyData*** string using javascript string methods

Request your server with this ***email*** and ***urlVerifyData***

Now query your database for this email and verify previously stored ***customUrl*** with user's ***urlVerifyData***

If they match, hola ! You got yourself a genuine user !!!

Answer (score 1):

I came across a Reddit post where one explained that one click on the link is not sufficient and might lead to errors and a failure of the verification. The logic is simple and legit, when the email containing the link is received, there might be link scanners (bots) on the SMTP server (Outlook, Gmail etc). Just like when you past a link on major social platforms, there is always a bot that hits the link. I did not try it myself but I believe Outlook scans some links (when you copy past a link it is converted to a thumbnail with page's content).
So this process oblige you to do a verification by two steps, maybe when the user clicks, he needs to past his own password used for signup (looks fine). Or provide a one time password with the email so that the user along with the verification link (maybe split then re-concat) the same token you send for verification and ask the user to enter that second part (this seems easier).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use regex for this:

`const emailCheck = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;`

This code checks if there is @ and . after the @(including @) also checks if there is at least 2 characters in the top domain. You can change the regex to suit your special case or just left it like this for email checks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear but still edited it.

Comment: The OP is asking how to send an account confirmation email, and not how to validate that a string is an email by using a regex.