# Verify Email address using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email-validation

What is the way to attain maximum success rate to verify the existence of an email address? Currently, I have been using the following package [npm package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-verify] in my Node.JS script to validate bulk email ids, but it treats a lot of valid email address as invalid.

Comment: Send a verification mail to the user.

Comment: @LGSon what I mean is how can I check if the email address actually exists or not without sending the actual email.

Comment: Check to see if the answer you desire is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092822/how-to-do-confirm-email-address-with-express-node)

Comment: You can't do that. To get 100% accuracy you need to make the user verify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I verify email address existence and domain name existence in javascript or nodeJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314277/how-should-i-verify-email-address-existence-and-domain-name-existence-in-javascr)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the comment, re: sending a verification email. I've toyed with packages that try to automate the process without involving the user, and they are all essentially heuristic in nature, yielding false negatives and/or false positives. I tried one which could not validate some university emails,  because it depended on the configuration of the SMTP server,  for example.

Comment: how do you do it for bulk email address checking programmatically?

Comment: @Nikhil Listen, you **can't** verify an email address w/o user verification. Read the possible duplicate's link answer and you will understand why