# What's the correct/standard practice to authenticate a user after registration?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, backend, cryptojs

I'm trying to authenticate a user after registration. What's the correct or standard way to go about it?

Using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39093058/4861207) as the way to implement it, in step 3, how can I generate the random hash to send to the users email? I see two different options:

1. crypto
2. JWT token

I'm currently using JWT for login, so would it make sense to use the same token for user verification? Why or why not, and if not, what's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question of whether you should use a crypto hash or a token is neither.

The hash you are generating to use as a verification method does not need to be cryptographically secure, it only needs to be a unique verification hash that is not easy to guess.
In the past I have used a v4 UUID with the [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) lib and it works just fine. You could also base64 some known piece of information about the user, like their id or email concatenated with something random, like the time in mircoseconds and a random hex string with substantial length, but honestly the time it takes to build out something like that is wasted when UUID v4 works just fine.

Your hash also doesn't *need* to be unique (different for each user, yes, but avoid all potential collisions? No) - hitting an endpoint with only the hash is not a great idea. The endpoint should also take an identifier for your user combined with the verification hash. This way, you don't need to worry about the hash being unique in your datastore. Find user by ID, check that verification hashes match, verify. I would only suggest that you obfuscate the user's know information in a way that you can decode on your end (ex: base64 encode their user ID + email + some const string you use).

[EDIT]

Verifying or validating a user is really just asking them to prove that the email address (or phone number) they entered does in fact exist and that it belongs to the user. This is an attempt to make sure the user didn't enter the information incorrectly or that the registration is spam. For this we don't need cryptographic authentication, a simple shared secret is more than enough.

When you store your user's registration data, you generate the shared secret you will use to verify the account. This can be anything that is (relatively) unique and contains enough length and entropy that it is not easy to be guessed. We aren't encoding or encrypting information that will be unpacked later, we are doing a literal string comparison to make sure the secret we provided to the user was echoed back to us intact. This is why a simple one-way hash is OK to use. I suggested a UUID v4 because the components of this hash are generated from random information (other versions of UUID make use of the machine's MAC or the time or other known pieces of information). You can use any method you like as long as it can't be easily decoded or guessed.

After you generate the verification hash you send it to the user (in a nicely formatted URL that they only need to click) in order for them to complete their account registration. URL guidelines are totally up to you, but here are some suggestions:

**BAD**

`/verify/<verification hash>`
or
`/verify?hash=<verification hash>`

With only the verification hash in the URL, you are relying on this value to be globally unique in your datastore. If you can reliably generate unique values that never contain collisions, then it would be OK, but why would you want to worry about that? Don't rely on the verification hash by itself.

**GOOD**

`/users/<id>/verify/<verification hash>`
or
`/users/<id>?action=verify&hash=<verification hash>`

Out of these two examples you can see that the point is to provide two pieces of data, 1. is a way to identify the user, and 2. the verification hash you are checking.
In this process you start by finding the user in your datastore by ID, and then literally compare the secret you generated and stored against the value given in the URL. If the user is found and the verification hashes match, set their account to Active and you're good to go. If the user is found but the hashes don't match... either you provided a malformed URL or someone is trying to brute force your verification. What you do here is up to you, but to be safe you might regenerate the hash and send out a new email and try the process again. This leads very quickly into a black hole about how to prevent spam and misuse of your system, which is a different conversation.

The above URL schemas really only work if your user IDs are safe for public display. As a general rule you should never use your datastore IDs in a URL, especially if they are sequential INTs. There are many options for IDs that you would use in a URL like UUID v1 or [HashIDs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashids) or any implementation of a short ID.

**ALSO**

A good way to see how this is done in the wild is to look at the emails you have received from other systems asking you to verify your own email address. Many may use the format:
`/account/verify/<very long hash>`

In this instance, the "very long hash" is usually generated by a library that either creates a datastore table just for the purpose of account verification (and the hash is stored in that table) or is decoded to reveal a user identifier as well as some sort of verification hash. This string is encoded in a way that is not easily reversible so it can not be guessed or brute forced. This is typically done by encoding the components with some sort of unique salt value for each string.

NOTE - while this method may be the most "secure", I only mention this because it is based on the typical methods used by third-party libs which do not make assumptions about your user data model. You can implement this style if you want, but it would be more work. My answer is focused your intent to do basic verification based on data in your user model.

**BONUS**

Many verification systems are also time constricted so that the verification URL expires after some period of time. This is easily able to be set up by also storing a future timestamp with your user data that is checked when the verification endpoint is hit and the user is found. What to do when an expired link is clicked is up to you, but the main benefit is to help you more easily clean up dead registrations that you know cannot be verified.

Comment: TBH I had to look up what UUID is, but it seems like it's similar to JWT except that you can't decode it. Is that correct? If so, I might as well use jWT since I am using it for login

Comment: UUIDs are like a sha1 hash, they are one-way hashes and no, you don't decode them. You don't need to decode a verification hash as you're not encoding or encrypting information that needs to be unpacked here. When you go to verify a user you are not authenticating them the same as a login, you're just making sure with reasonable certainty that they are the same user who provided the email address on registration. This step is a sanity check, it is not meant to be a cryptographically secure process. And re-using a JWT for this is not a great idea.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you very much for your guidance and patience!! So I would concatenate the email together with the hash, and send it over, correct? And is it not secure to send over JWT?

Comment: I'll amend my answer with some examples, just give me a couple minutes.