# Using Node.js and Mongoose what steps save a document and second document that references the first?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

[This brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39093058/11704859) by Soviut explains the logical steps necessary to use email verification to verify and activate new users.

However using `node.js` and `mongoose` I'm not sure what steps are necessary to save a document and then a second document that references the first document's ID.

1. Is there a way to save both documents simultaneously?
2. Do I need to save the first document and then use `findOne` to find it and copy its ID into the second document?
3. Is there a best practice for this type of problem?

Here are 2 example schema that may make this clearer.

**New User:**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    yourName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    businessName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});
```

**Temporary Hash used for validation:**

```
const NewUserHash = new mongoose.Schema({
    randomHash: {
        type: String
    },
    // what is the best practice for getting the ID from a UserSchema document and saving it here?
    referenceToUser: {  
        type: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        expires: 7200
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to validate the user once the user verifies the email, if this is the case why not have two schemas where when user registers for the first time just add the data in the temporary collection once the user sends the verification success request just fetch the data from the temporary collection and insert it into the permanent one, and delete the temporary record in the collection.

yes you can save both the documents using save but one after the other and yes u have to fetch the id first if you want to link, i would prefer the above method would be better.