# Is there any way to check particular email exist to send email using nodemailer in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

I want to check that user entered email is real email on which i can send emails or not ?
Is there any way to do this in nodejs or nodemailer ?

Comment: It looks like you want email verification. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092822/how-to-confirm-email-address-using-express-node)

Comment: It it correct. But is needs user confirmation of email. I want it at time of registration only. Like if the emails is real or exist then only register the user else not.

Comment: Look like a simple solution for your purposes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-existence. Should work.

Comment: will check this out. Thanks